# Converting this non-linear minimization problem to linear

Tags: calculus, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

**My Problem:** I would like to convert the following non-linear minimization problem into a linear programming problem, to solve it with the simplex method.

The non-linear function could be of any shape but with only one stationary point (the global minimum), supposing, for example, $f(x)=(x+3)^2$.
My minimization problem is like the following (but can potentially have more levels of nested functions):

$$
\min_{x_1, x_2} \quad f(3f(-x_1 + x_2) + f(2x_1-x_2)) \\
s.t \quad  0 < x_1 < 1 \quad \land \quad -1 < x_2 < 1
$$

---

**What I tried:** I thought to iteratively reduce my problem to another minimization problem on the argument of the function, trying to keep the argument as close as possible to the minimum. Something like that:

$$
\min_{x_1, x_2} \quad (3f(-x_1 + x_2) + f(2x_1-x_2) - argmin)^2 \\
s.t \quad  0 < x_1 < 1 \quad \land \quad -1 < x_2 < 1
$$

But I'm not sure if this could be a general solution and, moreover, I'm not even sure that a solution for my problem exists. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in general because the simplex method only works for linear objective and linear constraints. However, for the specialized case of a quadratic objective function a variant of the simplex method can be applied (search for Quadratic Programming Simplex Method by Philip Wolfe for details).

For your problem, can you compute gradients of your objective? If so, I suggest you use LBFGS-B, a variant of the well-known LBFGS method for nonlinear optimization that can also accommodate variable bounds. You can find this method implemented in e.g. Python in the scipy.optimize library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, I can compute the gradient. However, can I assume that a numerical method converges to the global minimum in this case? I mean, I know that the function f(x) has only one minimum, but what about the composition of this function?

Comment: For example, in the general form of: $f(k^0f(k_1^0x_1+k_2^0x_2+k_3^0x_3+...)+k_0^1f(k_1^1x_1+k_2^1x_2+k_3^1x_3+...)+...)$. Can I be sure that a numerical method find the global minimum?

Comment: If your function is convex, which is stronger than having a single global minimizer, then precomposing it with a linear function results in a another convex function. Same with summing convex functions. But composition of convex functions need not yield a function with a unique global min. Another area for you to look is the theory of quasiconvex functions. These are more general functions with unique global mins, but they don't have as nice of properties (i.e. the sum of quasiconvex functions need not be quasiconvex).

Comment: Thanks again for the insights, in particular for the theory of the quasiconvex functions. Assuming $f(x)$ convex, can I say that a numerical method (e.g., LBFGS-B) finds the global minimum in my problem? Even if the function is precomposed with a linear combination of itself? E.g., $f(f(f(x_1 - x_2) + f(x_1 + x_2) + f(x_1 + x_2)) - f(f(x_1 + x_2) - f(x_1 + x_2) - f(x_1 + x_2)))$ (I'm so sorry, it's difficult to read).

Comment: No, not in general. The objective itself must be convex. Whether or not this is true depends on your particular $f$.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question! It's sad because (in general) I can not solve my problem. I was thinking to transform my problem using the Lagrangian duality, in this case, I will have a linear sum of my convex function. However, it is not related to this question. Thanks again!

Comment: One additional suggestion: in practice, folks will often run LBFGS (or whatever nonlinear optimization method) many time from different starting points. Though you're not guaranteed to recover the global minimizer this way, the result is often good enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133097/discussion-between-davide-and-robert-bassett).